# why is the first row of the data frame printing twice?

Tags: python, pandas

so here is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[7,8],[22,33]],columns=["a","b"])
def func(k):
    print(k)
    return k**2
df[["a","b"]].apply(func,axis=1)
```

this is the output:-

```
a    1
b    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a    1
b    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a    7
b    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
a    22
b    33
Name: 2, dtype: int64
    a   b
0   1   4
1   49  64
2   484 1089
```

can someone explain why the below is repeated twice.

```
a 1
b 2
```

I think it should have printed just once.

Comment: I have tried at least 100 times but still I dont why its not working for me.Later I tried several online python compilers and I found out that some online compilers are priniting first row twice while some others not. for example ideone.com/l/python-3 , run the code on that website and you get the first row twice printed out. please let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Cannot reproduce either.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code I didn't get the first row twice.

```
a    1
b    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a    7
b    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
a    22
b    33
Name: 2, dtype: int64
a   b
0   1   4
1   49  64
2   484 1089
```

This was my output. I think you might have printed the first row somewhere else in the program.

Comment: I have tried at least 100 times but still I dont why its not working for me.Later I tried several online python compilers and I found out that some online compilers are priniting first row twice while some others not. for example   https://ideone.com/l/python-3   , run the code on that website and you get the first row twice printed out. please let me know if you figure it out.